# How to count the number of children in Kotlin Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to count the number of users in my database, but it still shows me zero. Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

```
     private var reff : DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
     private var IDusuario : Int = 0

     private fun countusuariosDB2() {

        reff.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    IDusuario = snapshot.childrenCount.toInt()
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
     }
```

Provided picture presents table `Users` with items.

[image]

Comment: What do you get in log? Try print out value when onDataChange is called.

Comment: None of the code you shared prints anything, so it's hard to say what's going on. Step 1 might be to stop ignoring errors, and implement `onCancelled`. At its minimum that should be: `override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) { Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException()) }`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.